# Trying to start up django app on Heroku: Application Error

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm using this [tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/deploy/README.html) trying to launch a Django web app on Heroku.

Get Application Error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

heroku logs:

```
2014-12-16T09:28:40.524655+00:00 heroku[run.3259]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createsuperuser`
2014-12-16T09:28:40.780639+00:00 heroku[run.3259]: State changed from starting to up
2014-12-16T09:28:56.130238+00:00 heroku[run.3259]: Process exited with status 0
2014-12-16T09:28:56.139256+00:00 heroku[run.3259]: State changed from up to complete
2014-12-16T09:29:06.983439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-reef-1163.herokuapp.com request_id=36ca5f9e-ed07-4b6e-96fb-767d70962e84 fwd="71.198.214.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-16T09:29:08.063637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-reef-1163.herokuapp.com request_id=0f3775df-0c97-4bc0-acf2-63e12130af39 fwd="71.198.214.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-16T09:29:08.785681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-reef-1163.herokuapp.com request_id=84fe76f2-dc74-4995-9cf9-d87cec886432 fwd="71.198.214.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-16T09:29:09.738623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-reef-1163.herokuapp.com request_id=cb87da0c-d6c3-4a27-a226-e2194343a633 fwd="71.198.214.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Does anybody have any guidance on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Consider running `heroku logs` and posting the output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I fixed it by installing django-toolbelt
and then running
`pip freeze requirements.txt`

and updating my Procfile as
`web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi`